# Pinecone returned id is not available in the list of tables

Tags: python

Good day,

Was working with Pinecone and followed [this guide](https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/table-qa) to create a QA.
In the last step:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

batch_size = 64

for i in tqdm(range(0, len(processed_tables), batch_size)):
    i_end = min(i+batch_size, len(processed_tables))
    batch = processed_tables[i:i_end]
    emb = retriever.encode(batch).tolist()
    ids = [f"{idx}" for idx in range(i, i_end)]
    to_upsert = list(zip(ids, emb))
    _ = index.upsert(vectors=to_upsert)

index.describe_index_stats()
```

my **processed_tables** is:

```
['Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2007,Industry Oil coal and electricity,345.03,United Kingdom,11.0,Economy,electr consumpt billion kilowatthour\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2006,Banking system access and depth,23.7,Mauritius,9.0,Economy,bank credit govern public enterpris percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1987,Industry Oil coal and electricity,0.04,Samoa,150.0,Economy,electr consumpt billion kilowatthour\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2019,Energy and environment,41.48,Republic of the Congo,184.0,Others,revenu minu product cost oil percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2006,Forecast from the IMF,39.83,Estonia,6.0,Others,invest forecast\n2006,Economic structure,57.87,Estonia,58.0,Others,valu ad servic sector percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2017,Energy mix,12.37,Zambia,42.0,Others,hydroelectr gener billion kilowatthour\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1998,Consumption and investment,1.4,Palestine,101.0,Others,capit invest billion usd\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1993,Child and maternal mortality,69.0,Sao Tome and Principe,137.0,Health,infant death per 1000 live birth\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1998,Shares of world totals,0.0,Lesotho,0.0,Economy,percent world import\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1982,Industry Oil coal and electricity,6.0,Thailand,59.0,Economy,oil product thousand barrel per day\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1980,Industry Oil coal and electricity,0.24,Ethiopia,102.0,Economy,electr product capac million kilowatt\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2002,International trade and investment,0.44,Portugal,301.0,Economy,foreign direct invest percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2014,Banking system efficiency and stability,108.52,Croatia,132.0,Economy,bank credit percent bank deposit\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1997,Industry Oil coal and electricity,0.0,United Arab Emirates,218.0,Economy,coal product thousand short ton\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2008,Consumption and investment,91.97,Sierra Leone,15.0,Others,household consumpt percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2015,Economic freedom indexes,69.7,Tanzania,148.0,Others,monetari freedom index 0-100\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n1967,GDP and economic growth,24031.13,Denmark,6.0,Economy,gdp per capita constant 2010 dollar\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2001,International trade and investment,56.78,Uzbekistan,230.0,Economy,trade open export plu import percent gdp\n',
 'Year,Subsector,Amount,Country,Rank,Sector,Indicator_cleansed\n2007,Industry Oil coal and electricity,3.21,Dominican Republic,82.0,Economy,electr product capac million kilowatt\n']
```

When I wanted to ask a query and find which table has the answer:

```
query = "electr consumpt billion kilowatthour in United Kingdom in 2007"
xq = retriever.encode([query]).tolist()
result = index.query(xq, top_k=1)
result
# {'matches': [{'id': '6505', 'score': 0.651521, 'values': []}], 'namespace': ''}
```

Result is not right, as it should be max `len(processed_tables)` not **6505**. What is 6505 and how to relate it to my list of tables?